# Call a method on the return value of a method reference

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a stream of files that I want to filter based on the ending of the file name:

```
public Stream<File> getFiles(String ending) throws IOException {
    return Files.walk(this.path)
            .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
            .map(Path::toFile)
            .filter(file -> file.getName().endsWith(ending));
}
```

While the lambda in the last line is not bad, I thought I could use method references there as well, like so:

```
 .filter(File::getName.endsWith(ending));
```

Or alternatively wrapped in parentheses. However, this fails with `The target type of this expression must be a functional interface`

Can you explain why this doesn't work?

Comment: A similar discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29146199/2711488

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can you explain why this doesn't work?

Method references are syntactical sugar for a lambda expression. For example, the method reference `File::getName` is the same as `(File f) -> f.getName()`.

Lambda expressions are "method literals" for defining the implementation of a functional interface, such as `Function`, `Predicate`, `Supplier`, etc.

For the compiler to know what interface you are implementing, the lambda or method reference must have a *target type*:

```
// either assigned to a variable with =
Function<File, String> f = File::getName;
// or assigned to a method parameter by passing as an argument
// (the parameter to 'map' is a Function)
...stream().map(File::getName)...
```

or (unusually) cast to something:

```
((Function<File, String>) File::getName)
```

Assignment context, method invocation context, and cast context can all provide target types for lambdas or method references.  (In all 3 of the above cases, the target type is `Function<File, String>`.)

What the compiler is telling you is that your method reference does not have a target type, so it doesn't know what to do with it.

Comment: Note that *classifier*::functionName isn't always equivalent to (o ->  *classifier*.functionName(*params*).  *classifier* could be an expression for instance; in `getReference()::method`, `getReference()` is called when the functional type is assigned/cast, while in `o -> getReference().method(o)`, `getReference()` is called each time the lambda is invoked.

Answer (score 3):

`File::getName` is a method reference and `String::endsWith` is as well. However they cannot be chained together. You could create another method to do this

```
public static Predicate<File> fileEndsWith(final String ending) {
    return file -> file.getName().endsWith(ending);
}
```

and then use it

```
.filter(MyClass.fileEndsWith(ending))
```

This doesn't buy you much if you're not re-using it though.

Comment: Is there a reason why the compiler doesn't let me chain them? wouldn't it be easy to recognize that the result of File::getName is a string?

Comment: or just `.filter(fileEndsWith(ending))`

Comment: @FAS A method reference is not a method invocation.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of helpers might assist in providing some semblance of what you wish for.  Using the helpers below, you can replace your lambda with an expression containing method references, like this:

```
// since your predicate is on the result of a function call, use this to create a predicate on the result of a function
public static <A,B> Predicate<A> onResult(Function<A,B> extractor, Predicate<B> predicate){
    return a -> predicate.test(extractor.apply(a));
}

// since your predicate involves an added parameter, use this to reduce the BiPredicate to a Predicate with one less parameter
public static <T,U> Predicate<T> withParam(BiPredicate<T,U> pred, U param){
    return t -> pred.test(t,param);
}

public Stream<File> getFiles(String ending) throws IOException {
    return Files.walk(Paths.get("."))
            .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
            .map(Path::toFile)
            .filter(onResult(File::getName, withParam(String::endsWith, ending)));
}
```