# Java List - How to group by a nested property?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

If I need to group by a property in Java 8, I can do this:

```
// cars is of type List<Car>
cars.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Car::getModel));
```

But how can I group the cars list by a property (e.g. make) of model? I've tried doing something like this:

```
Map<Make, List<Car>> listOfCarsByMake = cars.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Car::getModel::getMake));
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36798635/call-a-method-on-the-return-value-of-a-method-reference and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146199/java-8-chained-method-reference

Comment: Sorry... I missed finding that prior to posting. Thanks for the links.