# How to chain method references?

Tags: java

Is there any way to create a chain of method references like;

```
Chain chain = Product::getType::getTypeInfo::getTypeInfoId;
```

I want to create a generic null check method.

```
public Optional checkIfNull(Object object, Chain chain){
    return Optional.ofNullable(object).map(chain).isPresent();
}
```

Comment: I doubt it . . .

Comment: already discussed: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29146199/3959856

Comment: use a lambda? `product -> product.getType().getTypeInfo().getTypeInfoId()`

Comment: @user7 yes I linked that one

Comment: @JackFlamp That comment by user7 was posted when he flagged the question as duplicate.