# Double Colon lambda for two levels method invocation

Tags: java, lambda

Is there a way to use doubleColon to invoke second level method.
Example `ClassA::getClassBObject::classBMethod` in lambda invocation

Comment: Did you try ClassA.getClassBObject()::classBMethod?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146199/java-8-chained-method-reference) your question?  Summary: no, duplicate method references are not allowed

Comment: @JavaTechnical that simply doesnt work. getClassBObject isnt a static method

Comment: @Ravisha I have posted as an example, if it isn't a static method, use the reference instead.

Comment: @JavaTechnical that is the whole point of this question isn't it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are expecting is called chaining. Method references does not support chaining.

Read more about [Method References](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

Answer (score 7):

You could compose the functions:

```
((Function<ClassA, ClassB>) ClassA::getClassBObject).andThen(ClassB::classBMethod)
```

But you're probably better off with just `(x, arg) -> x.getClassBObject().classBMethod(arg)`.

More info on the composition approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32838924/2093695

Comment: no need to downvote. He mentioned that it is a solution but not a good one

Comment: @roundAbout I posted it because it's interesting, not because it's a good idea in real code. If anything, I think my answer shows by counterexample why you should just use a regular lambda.